# Scale Images within Slider for Mobile Devices

Tags: css, mobile, scaling, handheld

I am currently working on the mobile version of my website. I use the [NivoSlider](http://nivo.dev7studios.com/) throughout the site and unfortunately it doesn't seem to scale for mobile devices. I have a mobile specific section of my stylesheet and have tried using "width: 50%" and "max-width: 480px." They seem to shrink the area of the slider, but not the actual images themselves. Any thoughts or additional help would be great. The site is currently in the staging environment at http://www.staging.andrewpautler.com.

Comment: cool, awesome site. however dumbing it down for mobile phones is not advisable, if you make a dedicated mobile version you'll get more awesomeness points...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sitepoint has a get article on that [here](http://blogs.sitepoint.com/2011/01/11/responsive-web-design-with-html5-and-the-less-framework-3/)